# How to group items of a list based on their type transition?

Tags: python

My input is a list:

```
data = [
    -1, 0,
    'a','b', 1, 2, 3,
    'c', 6,
    'd', 'e', .4, .5,
    'a', 'b', 4,
    'f', 'g',
]
```

I'm trying to form groups (dictionary) where the keys are the strings and the values are the numbers right after them.

There are however three details I should consider:

- The list of data I receive can sometimes have leading non-string values that should be ignored
- The number of strings for each group is variable but the minimum is always 1
- Some groups can appear multiple times (example: `a/b`)

For all of that I made the code below:

```
start = list(map(type, data)).index(str)

wanted = {}
for i in data[start:]:
    strings = []
    if type(i) == str:
        strings.append(i)
        numbers = []
    else:
        numbers.append(i)
        
    wanted['/'.join(strings)] = numbers
```

This gives me nearly what I'm looking for:

```
{'a': [], 'b': [4], '': [4], 'c': [6], 'd': [], 'e': [0.4, 0.5], 'f': [], 'g': []}
```

Can you show me how to fix my code?

My expected output is this:

```
{'a/b': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [6], 'd/e': [0.4, 0.5], 'f/g': []}
```

Comment: @RobertMoskal. To be fair, a properly asked homework question is no different than any other properly asked question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a key function that tests if the current item is a string. To skip possible leading non-string items, fetch the first group, and fetch the next group again as a replacement if the first group items are not strings. For each group of items, if they are strings, join them as a key; otherwise extend the list under that key with the items. If the last group of items are strings, set it to an empty list as a default:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

output = {}
groups = groupby(data, lambda i: isinstance(i, str))
try:
    is_str, group = next(groups)
    if not is_str:
        is_str, group = next(groups)
except StopIteration:
    pass
else:
    for is_str, group in chain([(is_str, group)], groups):
        if is_str:
            key = '/'.join(group)
        else:
            output.setdefault(key, []).extend(group)
    if is_str:
        output.setdefault(key, [])
```

`output` becomes:

```
{'a/b': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [6], 'd/e': [0.4, 0.5], 'f/g': []}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/rcOSzV

Answer (score 3):

Here it is :) I've heavily commented everything

```
data = [
    -1, 0,
    'a','b', 1, 2, 3,
    'c', 6,
    'd', 'e', .4, .5,
    'a', 'b', 4,
    'f', 'g',
]
wanted = {}

i = 0 # Index of the data list

# Skipping the evenutal initial integers
while isinstance(data[i], int): # While the element is an integer
    i += 1 # Increment the index

while i < len(data): # While the index is not out of range
    key = '' # Initializing the key

    while i < len(data) and isinstance(data[i], str): # While the element is a string (character)
        if len(key) > 0: # If there is already a letter in the key, add a slash
            key += '/'
        
        key += data[i] # Add the letter to the key
        i += 1 # Increment the index
    
    if key not in wanted: # If the key is not in the dictionary, add it
        wanted[key] = [] # Initializing a new list for the key
    
    while i < len(data) and not isinstance(data[i], str): # Add all the numbers to the list
        wanted[key].append(data[i]) # Add the number to the list
        i += 1 # Increment the index

print(wanted)
```

Answer (score 3):

A variation of [blhsing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77744456/12671057):

```py
from itertools import groupby, chain

output = {}
groups = groupby(data, lambda i: isinstance(i, str))
nums = []
for is_str, group in groups:
    if is_str:
        nums = output.setdefault('/'.join(group), [])
    else:
        nums += group
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVFLagMxDKVbn0I7z1Bl-ktLCfQkIRRPxk4UZuzBlheh9CTdZNMeqqepx3YpVGDz_KQnPeSPr_nMR2cvl8_IZvX8feUGxQpeYCsgxeoO4RYzlEqi7CVCou4RHiq7T8xTxUPCUqerW6fz-KeDLFxXwizEQaLYCWG8m4BYe3ZuDEDT7DzDwbs492eE_VGRFcJFniMnV2_vIudCwrWoWQwjjGrqBwW0AQpkAyu71w0hBPZtK2ycFsl2J4zzqeI10Vg6ANkCwibbI1Pz5blEVRcXXdA8aKPiyI28kd3JkW1ygxbTgDar9Bj0P_11dSzE7MlyU7q1Ze91_b_f8AM)

Or:

```
output = {}
groups = groupby(data, lambda i: isinstance(i, str))
nums = None
for is_str, group in groups:
    if is_str:
        nums = output.setdefault('/'.join(group), [])
    elif nums is not None:
        nums += group
```

Comment: Argh this is what I wanted to achieve but my mind was preoccupied by the heap sort thing when I saw this question and answered it hastily. So pretty indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the initial step of finding `start`. Just roll that into the loop that does the rest of the work.

My suggestion would be to keep a `current_key` variable that keeps track of the current key, and update it when you see a new string, and a `current_values` list that keeps track of the values for that key. If the new string is just after another string (i.e. `current_values` is empty), modify the current key. If not, it counts as a new key. If the element is not a string, append it to a `current_values` list.

```
result = {}
current_key = []
current_vals = []
for ix, elem in enumerate(data):
    if isinstance(elem, str):
        if current_vals:    # list isn't empty
            key = '/'.join(current_key)
            if key not in result:
                result[key] = current_vals
            else:
                result[key].extend(current_vals)
            current_key = []
            current_vals = []
        
        current_key.append(elem)

    elif current_key:   # only consider values if a key has already been encountered
        current_vals.append(elem)

# finally, append the last key-value pair
key = '/'.join(current_key)
if key not in result:
    result[key] = current_vals
else:
    result[key].extend(current_vals)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jVHLTsMwELz7K1bqwankhkcLh0h8SVUhN9lQg@sE20GNEN8e1nFoEygFS46s2dndyUzd@l1lll1XSC/hAdYM6CxuBFyL/sklF3zLBRB0K2A5oDkh98O7oDdH@qQrunenPugbVwNQBuCJC7ZhjFl0jfa08P2D5Y21aPzjC7ZBweYIvEntIlJWFtRBAGrcgzKAptmjlR6ToHue9RtUCcop47w0OSaBKsB5O1QHxnh2FrAZaOU8dRruAfe1b4/0cKIofsXT50qZZKR1PuHR6EA1lQ/64u9lE0Y4EV8Tc0NTx1omVNQOLzanePBoimQ8Yarnh6nniieDvyrsTH8q6zosC47OGYsCR1YSJeuNrIxuIa@MUwVaoOENumCM7K3ZSQdSW5RFC1vEEGJeNcajxYKdU/Zt7wxKZaTWrYBYAL9D0JLCo/GLfh3UUlmoSvLqtVFh8Oy/oV8K@vdwLwQaQ/wzNFZbZXwSefOu@wQ)

Comment: This would incorrectly overwrite the previous value of a key if the input list ends with that key. Demo: https://ideone.com/aOsrQ9